# Backbone.save POST instead of PUT

Tags: post, backbone.js, put

just a short question:

Having the new instance of a model and issuing a `model.save()` with URL set to `/api/store/category`, Backbone issues a POST. According to my knowledge, it should use PUT, like mentioned in this ["PUT or POST: The REST of the Story"](http://jcalcote.wordpress.com/2008/10/16/put-or-post-the-rest-of-the-story/) blog post.

Who is right? BB or this article's author?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

According to [Backbone documentation](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-save), saving a new model will result in a POST request, and saving an existing model (having an id) will emit a PUT request.

> **save** *model.save([attributes], [options])*
>   ...
>   If the model isNew, the save will be a "create" (HTTP POST), if the model already
>   exists on the server, the save will be an "update" (HTTP PUT).

And if you are wondering if Backbone *should* use a POST for creation, check

1. [PUT vs POST in REST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/630453/put-vs-post-in-rest)
2. [RESTful web services](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer#RESTful_web_services) on Wikipedia

In the light of these articles, I'd say that, in the context of Backbone, the verbs are correctly used:

- saving a new model causes a change in the system, a new URL is added, the action is not idempotent, it should be a POST,
- saving a known model replaces a resource at a given URL, the action is idempotent, it should be a PUT.

Comment: Right, so in the response to the post request you should send newly created id back.

Comment: Thanks, I  already knew that. Maybe my question was a bit inaccurate. I was wondering if backbone is off-standard ;-)

Comment: @Jan I modified my answer to answer the choice of POST/PUT