# Model creates new row instead of being edited

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-views, backbone-model

I am working on app at moment, when I create a group the save function works great the model gets added to the collection, and saved to the database, however if I then want to edit the group I have just made, when I hit save the new model is created (and POST request) instead of  the data being edited and a PUT request being fired. Here is my save function - is there any reason I am not firing PUT requests when editing an exsisting model?

```
GroupModalHeaderView.prototype.save = function(e) {
  var $collection, $this;
  if (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }

  $this = this;
  if (this.$("#group-name").val() !== "") {
    $collection = this.collection;
    if (this.model.isNew()) {
      this.collection.add(this.model);
    }
    return this.model.save({ name: this.$("#group-name").val()}, {
      async: false,
      wait: true,
      success: function() {
        var modelID = $this.model.get('id');

        return this.modal = new app.GroupModalView({
          model: $this.collection.get(modelID),
          collection: $this.collection
        });
      }
    });
  }

};
```

This is my model defaults,

```
Group.prototype.defaults = {
  user_id: "",
  name: "New Group",
  email: "",
  url: "",
  telephone: "",
  mobile: "",
  fax: "",
  people: ""
};
```

Here is the console.log of `this.model` before it is saved,

```
    Group {cid: "c116", attributes: Object, _changing: false, _previousAttributes:    Object, changed: Object…}
        _changing: false
        _events: Object
        _pending: false
        _previousAttributes: Object
        email: ""
        fax: ""
        mobile: ""
        name: "New Group"
        people: ""
        telephone: ""
        url: ""
        user_id: ""
        wait: true
        __proto__: Object
        attributes: Object
        changed: Object
        cid: "c116"
        collection: GroupCollection
        id: 189
        __proto__: ctor
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason Backbone.js is firing a POST request instead of PUT is because your model does not have a unique identifier `id` associated with it.If there is not `id` attribute associated with your model, Backbone.js will always fire a POST request to save a new entry to db.

From backbone's website  :

> save model.save([attributes], [options]) ... If the model isNew, the
>
> save will be a "create" (HTTP POST), if the model already exists on
> the server, the save will be an "update" (HTTP PUT).

Read [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11013049/backbone-save-post-instead-of-put) for more information.

Comment: you will need to set the `id` in the model , before you dispatch a save request

Comment: But if i do console.log($this.model.get("id") in the success callback I can see the models ID?

Comment: alright, give me the console.log before you save the model to your db

Comment: if your model has an id before the save , it really not possible that backbone would dispatch a POST, because the model.isNew() would return false, what does model.isNew() return for you ?

Comment: When I save the first time isNew returns true, when I edit isNew returns false. After editing if I add what I think is a new group isNew returns false also.